# How to get disk information from computers on Active Directory with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have basic knowledge of PowerShell and I have been given a project that needs me to create a PowerShell script that gets all the computers on the domain in active directory and gather the free space/used space of each computer.

Comment: What have you tried? Have any work to show? What part exactly are you stuck at? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. If you need help learning how to code or troubleshoot something then this is the place for you. If you need code from scratch then you should hire a developer.

Comment: I will suggest looking at the `Get-ADComputer` and `Get-WMIObject` or `Get-CIMInstance` cmdlets to get you started.

Comment: As a pointer to get you started, have a look at the `Get-ADComputer`, `Get-Volume` and `Invoke-Command` cmdlets.  Also worth looking at is `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in order to get servers with low disk space:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Servers = Get-ADcomputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -like "*Server*"} -Properties Name, OperatingSystem -SearchBase "DC=yourDN,DC=local" | Select Name
$diskReport = Foreach($Server in $Servers)
{

    #$Status = "Offline"    
    $Name = $Server.Name
    #Make sure server is online
    if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    {

        #Get only 10%       
        Get-WMIObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $Name -Filter "DriveType=3" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {   ($_.freespace/$_.size) -le '0.1'}        
    }
    else
    {
        #Server is offline
    }       

}

$lowservers = $diskreport | Select-Object @{Label = "Server Name";Expression = {$_.SystemName}},
        @{Label = "Drive Letter";Expression = {$_.DeviceID}},
        @{Label = "Total Capacity (GB)";Expression = {"{0:N1}" -f( $_.Size / 1gb)}},
        @{Label = "Free Space (GB)";Expression = {"{0:N1}" -f( $_.Freespace / 1gb ) }},
        @{Label = 'Free Space (%)'; Expression = {"{0:P0}" -f ($_.freespace/$_.size)}}
```

This will first pull all your objects using Get-ADComputer. Then it just does a simple foreach to put everything into $diskReport. The $lowservers is just to clean it up a bit.

You can do whatever you want with $lowservers. I have mine on a scheduled task to run every Monday and Friday. Then send out an email if it finds something low.